# Having issues getting a group or second join to work

Tags: sql

I have been bashing my face into this issue for a few hours now. Our SQL tables were unfortunately not created by myself and I don't have the option to remake them in a way that would help me here.

I am trying to select and group a fair amount of data and group that, then group it again in order to get all Meetings 1-4 on 1 row

Here is my convoluted query that I have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  r."ERHomeID",
  r."ReportType",
  r."Name",
  (
    Case
    When a."ActivityType"  = 'Initial Assessment Interview' then a."SubmittedOn"
    Else 0
    END) as 'Meeting 1',
  (
    Case
    When r.ReportType  = 'Life Safety Inspection Worksheet (2029) (Initial)' then r."ReportDate"
    Else 0
    END) as 'Meeting 2',
  (
    Case
    When r.ReportType  = 'Background Information Interview' then r."ReportDate"
    Else 0
    END) as 'Meeting 3',
  (
    Case
    When a."ActivityType"  = 'Final Interview' then a."ActivityDate"
    Else 0
    END) as 'Meeting 4',
  (
    datediff(a."SubmittedOn", a."ActivityDate")
  ) as 'Days to Completion'
FROM  "Reports" AS  r
JOIN "Activities" AS  a ON r."ERHomeID"  = a."ERHomeID"
WHERE          r."name"  like '%Winfrey%'
```

Here is what it outputs

```
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| r.ERHomeID | r.ReportType | r.Name  | Meeting 1           | Meeting 2        | Meeting 3        | Meeting 4        | Days to Completion |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | Staff Review | Winfrey | 0                   | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                  |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | Staff Review | Winfrey | 2018-10-30 00:04:31 | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                  |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | Staff Review | Winfrey | 0                   | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                  |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | Staff Review | Winfrey | 0                   | 0                | 0                | 2018-12-17 16:30 | 0                  |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | References   | Winfrey | 2018-10-30 00:04:31 | 0                | 0                | 0                |                    |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | References   | Winfrey | 0                   | 2018-12-17 16:30 | 0                | 0                |                    |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | References   | Winfrey | 0                   | 0                | 0                | 2018-12-17 16:30 |                    |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | References   | Winfrey | 0                   | 0                | 2018-12-17 16:30 | 0                |                    |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I need it to output this.

```
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| r.ERHomeID | r.ReportType | r.Name  | Meeting 1           | Meeting 2        | Meeting 3        | Meeting 4        | Days to Completion |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | Staff Review | Winfrey | 2018-10-30 00:04:31 | 0                | 0                | 2018-12-17 16:30 | 0                  |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 1          | References   | Winfrey | 2018-10-30 00:04:31 | 2018-12-17 16:30 | 2018-12-17 16:30 | 2018-12-17 16:30 | 0                  |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I am just having a lot of trouble getting 2 separate joins to work on for the r.ERHomeID and another for the r.ReportType

Comment: Using `group by`, you need to group the columns that are desired to be unique.

Comment: I tried adding GROUP BY r.ReportType but i get the following  "Please ensure that all non-aggregate columns used in the SELECT clause are also used in GROUP BY clause."

Comment: This error indicates that all the columns that you are selecting in the query must be either in the `group by` clause or aggregated to a single value.

Comment: On a side note: you can remove all those double quotes, as your table and column names are fine without them. And for the alias names with spaces you are using the wrong quotes. It must be double quotes. Single quotes are not for names, but for string literals. So it should be `AS "Meeting 1"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `group by`, you can group the columns that are desired to be distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
r."ERHomeID",
r."ReportType",
r."Name",

MAX((Case
When a."ActivityType"  = 'Initial Assessment Interview' then a."SubmittedOn"
Else 0
END)) as 'Meeting 1',

MAX((Case
When r.ReportType  = 'Life Safety Inspection Worksheet (2029) (Initial)' then r."ReportDate"
Else 0
END)) as 'Meeting 2',

MAX((Case
When r.ReportType  = 'Background Information Interview' then r."ReportDate"
Else 0
END)) as 'Meeting 3',

MAX((Case
When a."ActivityType"  = 'Final Interview' then a."ActivityDate"
Else 0
END)) as 'Meeting 4',

MAX((datediff(a."SubmittedOn", a."ActivityDate"))) as 'Days to Completion'

FROM  "Reports" AS  r 
JOIN "Activities" AS  a ON r."ERHomeID"  = a."ERHomeID"
WHERE r."name"  like '%Winfrey%'
GROUP BY r."ERHomeID", r."ReportType", r."Name"
```

`Max` is used only because other columns that are not participated in the `group by` need to be aggregated somehow.

Comment: I'd remove all those `Else 0`. They are only obfuscating things.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now that I see it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You simply want conditional aggregation.  I would recommend writing it something like this:

```
SELECT r."ERHomeID", r."ReportType", r."Name",
       MAX(CASE WHEN a."ActivityType"  = 'Initial Assessment Interview' 
                THEN a."SubmittedOn"
           END) as Meeting_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.ReportType  = 'Life Safety Inspection Worksheet (2029) (Initial)' 
                THEN r."ReportDate"
           END) as Meeting_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r.ReportType  = 'Background Information Interview' 
                THEN r."ReportDate"
           END) as Meeting_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN a."ActivityType"  = 'Final Interview' 
                THEN a."ActivityDate"
           END) as Meeting_4
      DATEDIFF(MIN(a."SubmittedOn"), MAX(a."ActivityDate")) as Days_to_Completion
FROM "Reports" r JOIN
     "Activities" a
     ON r."ERHomeID" = a."ERHomeID"
WHERE r."name" like '%Winfrey%'
GROUP BY r."ERHomeID", r."ReportType", r."Name";
```

Notes:

- I think the `MAX()` pretty much does what you want.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  I changed the names so they do not need to be escaped.
- I would recommend removing the double quotes from all the table and column names.  That just makes the queries harder to write and to read.
- I am not sure what the calculation is for the `datediff()`.  This is a reasonable guess.